# How can I use hyperspectral images with nvdia digits ( caffe )?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I have an image which has 48 bands. I used PCA then band number is reduced to 12 for representing %99.9 data. But png, jpg hold only 3 bands. How can I use hyperspectral images with Nvidia digits ( Caffe )?

I tried to combine 4 pictures with 3 bands. But the result is very bad. I do not have a problem when I make the Arff file and give it to WEKA. But I could not figure out how to use hyperspectral images with neural networks.

What is the best way of using hyperspectral images with neural networks (Nvidia digits ( Caffe ))?

Comment: you have a few options 1) implement imageloader layer in caffe which can load multiple bands saved as different png images and concatenate them yourself 2) use hdf5 3)use lmdb also require you to load the image data and concatenate yourself